# MVC3 Catch all path segments in URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iframe, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to embed a legacy Area of our MVC3 application into an iframe within the website's new root layout.

The aim is to save time and avoid Javascript and CSS styling conflicts between new and old sections of the website.

I have so far been able to conditionally redirect traffic from the old Area to a new URL within the `OnActionExecuting` method in the Area's controllers.

e.g. `http://localhost:80/Area/Account/Profile` to `http://localhost:80/App/Area/Account/Profile`

My trouble now is setting up a catch all route that can pass the entire URL to a specific action and controller so I can take the URL and apply it to the iFrame.

I have this in my routing but it does not pass the path to the action and if there is more than one segment in the path it does not hit the route at all:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "AppRedirect", // Route name
    "App/{*page}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "App", page = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Is there a way a can get the route working with the full path including all segments?

Or is there a better way to embed one of the projects Areas into an iFrame within the new root layout, while maintaining a readable URL similar to the old configuration? I do not want to modify the structure or routing configuration of the old Area if it can be helped.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how many possible segments there could be in the URLs? You could set up several routes (heirarchically - most segments filtering down to one) pointing to the same controller action and do the rest in there.

```
routes.MapRoute(
"AppRedirect2", // Route name
"App/{seg1}/{seg2}", // URL with parameters
new { controller = "Home", action = "App", seg1 = UrlParameter.Optional, seg2 = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
"AppRedirect1", // Route name
"App/{seg1}", // URL with parameters
new { controller = "Home", action = "App", page = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

etc...